# get string from object text using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, object

I have some HTML that contain this script

```
   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', 'UA-117747539-1', {
        'custom_map': {
            'dimension1': 'novel',
            'dimension2': 'chapter',
            'dimension5': 'novel_id',
            'dimension6': 'chapter_id'
        }
    });
    // Sends the custom dimension to Google Analytics.
    gtag('event', 'novel_dimension', {
        'novel': 'I&#039;m The Most Evil Support Class【Talker】And I&#039;ll Subdue The Strongest Clan In The World',
        'chapter': 'Chapter: 002',
        'novel_id': '198',
        'chapter_id': '7756'
    });
```

I want to get the data novel_id and chapter_id from the object above using regex.

Is that possible?

Comment: novel_id is part of the jsonobject in gtag

Comment: my friend read the content, i have html string that contain this data and want to extract those values using regex

Comment: OH ... so what you posted, the whole thing, is a string! sorry

Comment: @mplungjan - I think you fell for the same problem I did - the content shown is in a STRING

Comment: What you posted is not a STRING. Please post the ACTUAL string unless you do not have a string but actual HTML and JS Object

Comment: @JaromandaX If it is truly a string, we can still use proper JS to get at it -  see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955318/295783)

Answer (score 1):

If you REALLY have a string you can do this better than using a regex

```js
const str = `window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', 'UA-117747539-1', {
        'custom_map': {
            'dimension1': 'novel',
            'dimension2': 'chapter',
            'dimension5': 'novel_id',
            'dimension6': 'chapter_id'
        }
    });
    // Sends the custom dimension to Google Analytics.
    gtag('event', 'novel_dimension', {
        'novel': 'I&#039;m The Most Evil Support Class【Talker】And I&#039;ll Subdue The Strongest Clan In The World',
        'chapter': 'Chapter: 002',
        'novel_id': '198',
        'chapter_id': '7756'
    });`
    
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.textContent=str;
document.querySelector("head").appendChild(script)
const dim = window.dataLayer[2][2]; // or recursively find object containing key===novel
console.log(dim.novel_id,dim.chapter)
```

If actually an html page with a script then just

```js
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

function gtag() {
  dataLayer.push(arguments);
}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'UA-117747539-1', {
  'custom_map': {
    'dimension1': 'novel',
    'dimension2': 'chapter',
    'dimension5': 'novel_id',
    'dimension6': 'chapter_id'
  }
});
// Sends the custom dimension to Google Analytics.
gtag('event', 'novel_dimension', {
  'novel': 'I&#039;m The Most Evil Support Class【Talker】And I&#039;ll Subdue The Strongest Clan In The World',
  'chapter': 'Chapter: 002',
  'novel_id': '198',
  'chapter_id': '7756'
});

const dim = window.dataLayer[2][2]; // or recursively find object containing key===novel
console.log(dim.novel_id, dim.chapter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i was able to solv it this way instead

```
   var novRegex = /.*?novel_id'\s?:\s?'([\w\s]+)'/i
        var chapRegex = /.*?chapter_id'\s?:\s?'([\w\s]+)'/i

        var x1 = undefined;
        var x2 = undefined;
        var html = dom.head.innerText;
        x1 = html.match(novRegex)[1]
        x2 = html.match(chapRegex)[1]
```

Comment: Would you perhaps be kind as to answer our questions? We spent time trying to help you..

Comment: friend your answer was good but not right, remember i wrote that the html string contain more data than the above data. so your answer wont work for me but i still voted upp for you it still should be good right